# Python: are seek(0) and open() essentially doing the same thing?

Tags: python, seek

So I'm working on "learning python the hard way" exercise 20, and the lesson introduces the "seek()" function for referencing files. In this instance, we have:

```
def rewind(f):
  f.seek(0)
```

creating a function to invoke seek(0), which means making a reference point to the beginning of the file used in the program. Now, in several lessons, we have assigned a variable to be used to open a file, in this case, `current_file = open(input_file)`.

My question is, whether using seek to open a file from the beginning with (0) would be the same thing as using the open command again, like `open(current_file)`. What are the differences if there are any? Here is the code for the whole lesson:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Comment: Seek doesn't open the file, it rewinds the current file. I'm sure that's what you meant but _"using seek to open a file from the beginning with (0)"_ is different. Can you clarify?

Comment: btw `open(..., "a")` opens file and moves pointer to the end of file so it does  `seek(0, 2)`

Comment: FYI: http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Answer (score 2):

No, because as your example code shows, [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) works on an *open file object* whereas [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) works on a *file name*. The difference is a little subtle, a brief example might make it clearer:

```
f = open('myfile.txt')
f.seek(5)
```

You could always reopen the file instead of seeking to zero, but that would be extra overhead.

Comment: Beyond the extra overhead, for open files without a name (possibly because the file has been deleted immediately after being opened, as in some implementations of `tempfile.TemporaryFile`), you _can't_ reopen it, but you can seek back to the start. Similarly, for other file-like objects like `gzip.open`, just calling plain `open` on `fileobj.name` would not get you equivalent behavior to seeking backwards, because you'd have the wrong handler.